Gradle build failure: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app
enter image description hereI'm facing an issue with my Android project during the Gradle build process. The error I'm receiving is:
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'. my sdk version 34 and gradle 9.0
I try to turn off the Toggle Offline Mode but t doesn't resolve my problem
Ithink I have problem with this implementation :   implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.4'

This question is similar to: implementing the com.amulyakhare library in android studio. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

no this problem appears when i update android studio to the latest version and gradle also to 9.0

Gradle 9.0? I didn't know it was released yet. All I can see on the Gradle website is 8.10.
